# One word for motivating someone through personal experience

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word used to describe an action where one motivates an individual or a group of people to do something through sharing their own experience/journey.
Learning from experience is `wisdom`. What describes motivating people by imparting wisdom?

Answer (score 1):

There is one word for what you ask, that is so far untainted by by commerce.  It is *mentor* and its cognate verb *to mentor* and abstract noun *mentorship*.  This does refer to someone who helps people in schools or in the earlier stages of their careers to gain the benefit of their experience.  Such people might be older, more experienced colleagues, or they might be retired people.  In schools, they can be older pupils, who ‘know the ropes’ supporting younger pupils.

I myself support sixth formers in a school, under a voluntary scheme operated by the Royal Society of Arts and Commerce (RSA) of which I am a Fellow.  Much has been written on the subject of mentorship.

The word itself goes back to the aged Achaean (*Greek*) advisor to the Mycenaean king and leader of the expedition to recover Helen from Ilion (*Troy*), Agamemnon, whose name was Mentor.

So the verb you might need is *to mentor*.